# выбор элемента на котором использовалась функция

Tags: javascript, jquery

Собственно есть вот такая вот кнопка:

```
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="changeSign(this.value)" name="r_abs_sph_sign" id="r_abs_sph_sign_min"/>
```

При клике, её атрибут value с минуса, должен поменяться на плюс. Вот собственно и вопрос - как с помощью jQuery в функции changeSign() выбрать эту кнопку и поменять её значение?

P.S.: На странице таких кнопок будет штук восемь, поэтому хотелось бы сделать всё это с помощью одной функции а не писать для каждой кнопки свою.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 однотипных штук и у всех `id`?
Подумайте над архитектурой ещё, это плохой подход, лучше использовать классы

```js
$(function(){
  $('.r_abs_sph_sign_min').click(function(){ // Перебираем все кнопки с классом r_abs_sph_sign_min и слушаем событие клика
    // this указывает на кнопку
    this.value = this.value === '-' ? '+' : '-'; // Меняем знак в зависимости от того, какой сейчас
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="-" name="r_abs_sph_sign" class="r_abs_sph_sign_min"/> | 
<input type="button" value="-" name="r_abs_sph_sign" class="r_abs_sph_sign_min"/> | 
<input type="button" value="-" name="r_abs_sph_sign" class="r_abs_sph_sign_min"/> | 
<input type="button" value="-" name="r_abs_sph_sign" class="r_abs_sph_sign_min"/> | 
<input type="button" value="-" name="r_abs_sph_sign" class="r_abs_sph_sign_min"/> | 
<input type="button" value="-" name="r_abs_sph_sign" class="r_abs_sph_sign_min"/>
```

Comment: А не подскажите как называется данная конструкция? (this.value = this.value === '-' ? '+' : '-';)

Comment: @JIyHaTuK, Это тернарный оператор ( https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#оператор-вопросительный-знак ). Удобная вещь для небольших условий.